# Rails Date After

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I need to do a query on Rails model time stamps (`created_at` and `updated_at`) finding all records after a specified date. When executing the query:

```
Item.where("created_at > :date OR updated_at > :date", date: "2011-05-29")
> SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE (created_at > '2011-05-29' OR updated_at > '2011-05-29')
```

It includes records like:

```
attributes: 
  created_at: 2011-05-29 16:07:10.664227
  updated_at: 2011-05-29 16:07:10.664229
```

However, this date isn't greater than the one specified. Any simple way to fix this query? Thanks.

**Edit:**

I've also tried doing:

```
Item.where("created_at > :date OR updated_at > :date", date: "2011-05-29 16:07:10")
```

With the same result, however adding the fraction of seconds stamp as well gives the correct result.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Say you want records starting 30th May:

Then search for records that are >= `2011-05-30 00:00:00`:

```
some_date = Time.now
Item.where("created_at >= :date OR updated_at >= :date", date: some_date.tomorrow.beginning_of_day)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that the created_at and updated_at are datetime, so if you only pass a date it defaults the time to 00:00:00 and anything past that is obviously greater. So the records you are seeing are past that date since the hour is greater.

Take a look at your precision, you can either pass 1 more day, and I'll show anything above that day, even greater for a second, or simply pass the hour as 23:59:59.

Comment: Do `datetime` fields require a fraction of second to be specified as well? Thanks!

Comment: No, I would problably just add 1 full day, or just 23:59:59 both would give you good enough precision.

Answer (score 3):

You can use my gem [by_star](https://github.com/radar/by_star) to do this.

```
Post.after(date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately SQL disagrees with you:

```
mysql> SELECT '2011-05-30 12:00:00' > '2011-05-30';
+--------------------------------------+
| '2011-05-30 12:00:00' > '2011-05-30' |
+--------------------------------------+
|                                    1 |
+--------------------------------------+
```

And for comparing dates with datetimes, MySQL has [this to say](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-types.html):

> A DATE value is coerced to the DATETIME type by adding the time portion as '00:00:00'.